# ERR node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, package.json

I have a problem when i execute the command

```
npm install
```

every time it shows me

> npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
>
> node --version v12.14.1 npm --version 6.13.4

I am not able to resolve this issue. I tried to modify the package.json with the

```
node-sass": "4.12.0
```

in "dependencies" and "devDependencies", but it dose't resolve anything.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete node modules
2. Delete package.lock.json
3. Run

```
npm i --force --package-lock-only
```

4. Run

```
npm i --force
```

will work 100%, if any issue reply here

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
npm audit
npm audit fix
```

Or use unsafe Tag

```
npm i node-sass --unsafe-perm=true
```

if still dosen't work, refresh dependencies like

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Delete node_modules folder
3. Run npm install again.